# jQuery plugin working fine on localhost, but on web server messes with bg-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have build a small lightweight plugin to display a cookie message. Testing on my localhost works fine, no web pages are affected, however, when I send the files over to the server, it is either:

- preventing a bg-image from loading
- Or.. messing with its visibility or function

jsfiddle (javascript file): http://jsfiddle.net/dvQYS/

Has anybody got an idea why they are messing up on the server pc? (even though its client side code) This is what i believe the cause could be since its working fine on the localhost server

I have answered the question below.

Comment: did you change the domain of your cookie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone looking for something similar:

I moved the script call to the top of the file, for some reason calling it at the bottom messed with it, so anyone experiencing these problems try that!